# Gitlab CI use extends from external local yml in several templates

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline, extends, gitlab-ci.yml

I tried to share tags and template between templates with include and extends but I got the following error:

> `jobs:monitoring:cache config contains unknown keys: **extends**.`

Here is my folder structure:

```
|_ .gitlab
|_______ ci
|_________ tags-template.yml
|_________ install.yml
|_________ config.yml
|_________ monitoring.yml
|_ .gitlab-ci.yml
```

I have a base gitlab file **.gitlab-ci.yml**

```bash
include: 
  - local: '.gitlab/ci/install.yml'
  - local: '.gitlab/ci/config.yml'
  - local: '.gitlab/ci/monitoring.yml'


variables:
  NODE_VERSION: '16.14.0'
  NODE_IMAGE: 'node:${NODE_VERSION}-alpine'

stages:
  - install
  - config
  - monitoring
```

I also a file that contain tags and templates, **tags-template.yml** that will we be used by others template

```bash
.aws_runner:
  tags:
    - aws

.aws_runner_intra: 
  tags:
    - intra

.dependencies_cache:
  key:
    files:
      - package.json

.cypress_artifacts:
  when: always

.set_env: &set_env |
  set HTTP_PROXY="http://web-proxy.abc"
  unset https_proxy http_proxy HTTPS_PROXY

.job_tmpl:
  extends: .aws_runner
  image: ${CYPRESS_DEPENDENCIES_IMAGE}
  script:
    - *set_env
    - npm run ${TARGET}
  cache:
    extends: .dependencies_cache
```

and my **monitoring.yml** file

```bash
stages:
  - monitoring

xoxo-services:
  stage: monitoring
  variables:
    USER: 'azerty'
    ARGET: 'test:services:monitoring'
  extends: .job_tmpl
```

I read the documentation tried also to use reference tags but get no success:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags

when I use reference tags (`- !reference [.job_tmpl]`) I have the following error in vscode

Unresolved tag: !referenceYAML

How can I include **.job_tmpl** into the 5 files ?